# How to select a query if exist then select or select a another

Tags: sql, database, select, db2, conditional-statements

I have a report looks something like this:

| numberOrder | timestamp | id | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2021-06-23-14.00.00.232425 | 11 | done |
| 12 | 2021-06-30-18.00.00.224525 | 22 | done |
| 12 | 2021-07-01-01.00.00.224525 | 23 | done |
| 12 | 2021-08-01-01.00.00.224525 | 25 | cancel |

This is done with SQL:

```
SELECT numberOrder, timestamp, id, status 
from order 
where status <> 'cancel'
order by id 
fetch first row only
```

The result return this:

| numberOrder | timestamp | id | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2021-06-23-14.00.00.232425 | 11 | done |

How can I result the cancel order only in the same query if I don't have 2 or more orders. If I have only one order and the status is cancel (no order done). The result with only show the order with cancel. But if I have more than 2 orders (orders1 : done, orders2 : done and orders3 = cancel) The result should be only orders1 : done.

The report :

| numberOrder | timestamp | id | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2021-06-23-14.00.00.232425 | 11 | cancel |

```
SELECT numberOrder, timestamp, id, status 
from order 
where (status <> 'cancel' or status = 'cancel') -- always true the condition
order by id 
fetch first row only
```

the result :

| numberOrder | timestamp | id | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2021-06-23-14.00.00.232425 | 11 | cancel |

Comment: `order by id, case when status = 'cancel' then 2 else 1 end`

Comment: What does it mean "if I don't have 2 or more orders"? Does it mean, that for some `numberOrder` you must get not more than 1 record with the smallest `id` among rows with: `status <> 'cancel'` first (if they exist), `status = 'cancel'` if there are no rows with `status <> 'cancel'`? If not, then explain why the row with `id=11` got `status='cancel'`, if it has `status='done'` in your example data.

Comment: I mean if I have orders : done, done and cancel, I only show the done. But if the report have only the cancel and not the done order I will only show the cancel order

Answer (score 1):

If you are only ever selecting one row, ordering by status works,

```
SELECT numberOrder, timestamp, id, status 
from order
order by id, status DESC
fetch first row only
```

If you want to select an arbitrary number of rows, with cancel only if there are no "done",

```
SELECT numberOrder, timestamp, id, status 
from order
WHERE (status = 'done'
       or (SELECT status FROM order ORDER BY status DESC LIMIT 1) != 'done')
order by id
```

Not sure if the last solution is optimal, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH T (numberOrder, id, status) AS
(
VALUES
  (12, 11, 'done')
, (12, 22, 'done')
, (12, 23, 'done')
, (12, 25, 'cancel')

, (13, 10, 'cancel')
, (13, 11, 'cancel')
)
SELECT numberOrder, id, status
FROM
(
SELECT T.*, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY numberOrder ORDER BY DECODE (status, 'cancel', 1, 0), id) AS RN_ 
FROM T
)
WHERE RN_ = 1
```

The result is:

| NUMBERORDER | ID | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 11 | done |
| 13 | 10 | cancel |

If the result is unexpected, provide the correct one on the sample data above.

Comment: I mean if I have orders : done, done and cancel, I only show the done. But if the report have only the cancel and not the done order I will only show the cancel order

Comment: This means, that my answer above should work for you...